# Is there a browser compatiblity issue with relative image paths in .css files?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have `.css` files with relative references to images like this:

```
BODY
{
    BACKGROUND: url(bg.gif);
}
```

where the `bg.gif` file is located in the same folder as the `.css` file. This seems to work fine in my testing but I notice some errors in my logs that indicate that some browsers are trying to find `bg.gif` in the same folder as the `.html` page that refers to the `.css` file, not the folder where the `.css` file is.

Here's an example of one such `HTTP_USER_AGENT`: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7`

I have tried searching this online and find conflicting information.

Comment: if the problem persist add the full path. but i dont think it should be a problem with any browsers

Comment: But that doesn't work if I locate the web app in a subfolder sometime.  It also doesn't allow me to move the css folder easily.

Comment: Do you have canonical set? Are you using mod-rewrite? These can cause issues with resolving the path in css files. It may be more of a server issue than a browser issue.

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski, what is "canonical"? Can you send links?

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes, none of the modern browsers have any such problems. Relative paths are very well supported.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of anything having this problem...I'd suggest tying to link them with the full relative path, or perhaps placing them into a images folder and linking through that (sort of like a reset, 2nd chance).

Answer (score -1):

that can be something to do with base url for the page. You might want to specify it so the browser knows how to access files.

Add base element to head (as below) section and let me know

```
<head>
    <base href="http://mysite.com/images/" target="_blank" />
</head>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Adding a base tag is not needed and will likely have unintended consequences