# Should I make all links relative or absolute

Tags: html, url, hyperlink

Since I started making my own web applications, rather than managing other peoples, I have fallen into the habit of making each reference url start from / .

This was becuase I wanted a convention, and I would find I was testing/deploying apps that used relative and absolute(/ not including http://....) urls in the app.

What convention should I be using for web applications, and will I run into problems with either approach (Aside from not being able to run apps in different folders with the absolute one)

Is there a benefit I get from using absolute? Or would relative always work just as well, and give me an added benefit of portability?

Comment: Up to a few days ago, I would have said relative doesn't have any disadvantages so why not stick to that? But then [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134455/is-there-a-browser-compatiblity-issue-with-relative-image-paths-in-css-files) happened, and now I have doubts.

Answer (score 0):

No benefit from absolute versus relative as long as the reference gets properly resolved. As for portability, this is one of those "it depends" situations.

Answer (score 0):

For external page it is obviously that you can use only absolute paths. But for internal links I would suggest to use relative paths, as you'll gain from portability of the site.

Comment: so if I have two html files and I want to host on a shared hosting account (think hostgator, Namecheap, etc), it will be alright if I use relative links in my 2 html files and upload them? Then how will the hosting service know which is the main html; must one of them be named index.html and can the rest be stored in pages/features.html?

Comment: If I understand you right, then you're after: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base